# C# switch clause on boolean variable

Tags: c#, switch-statement, boolean

I have a piece of code, that is checking if a boolean variable is true and based on the condition, I perform operations accordingly:

```
bool result = true;
bool isTrue = false;
CheckIsTrue(ref isTrue);

if (result)
{
   if (isTrue)
   //Perform action
}
```

I have a need to perform another operation, if the variable is set to false:

```
 if (result)
 {
    if (isTrue)
    {
      //Perform action
    } 
    else if(actionType == 6)
    {
      //Perform action, isTrue = false.
    }
 }
```

For readability and maintainability reason, I decided to change the above to:

```
 if (result)
 {
     switch (isTrue)
     {
       case true:
               //perform action on isTrue
           break;
              default:
                   switch (actionType)
                   {
                      case 6:
                         //Perform action on 6
                       break;
                          default:
                        //Perform default action        
                       break;
                   }
            break;
     } 
}
```

My question is: is it smart to use `swicth.. case...` on boolean variables? 
This is the best way I have considered to simplify my code, however I am not sure on how correct this truly is.

Comment: I believe this question is more suitable for [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) site. If you want to keep your code readable, try to stick with only one level of indentation.

Comment: I'd say this is primarily opinion-based, but personally your second code sample is far more readable than using multiple nested switch statements like in your third. If you have lots of `actionType` values you want different execution paths for, I'd personally use `if (isTrue) { ... } else { switch (actionType) { ....} }`

Comment: Using switch statement for bool is not good coding practice so you should avoid it. Just use if/else for bool and switch inside or call another function to handle the switch statement.

Comment: If you want to use switch, please consider my answer as it is a very readable way of using a switch in your case.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy example, stub or hypothetical code like this is off-topic on Code Review and would get closed soon. See https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With only one level of indentation and proper variable names:

```
if (!actionShouldBePerformed) // instead of result
   return;

if (defaultActionShouldBePerformed) // insted of isTrue
{
   //Perform action
   return;
}

if (actionType == ActionType.NameOfType) // instead of magic number 6
   // Perform another action
```

Further reading: [Replace Nested Conditional with Guard Clauses](https://refactoring.com/catalog/replaceNestedConditionalWithGuardClauses.html)

Answer (score 2):

I think `switch` statement isn't good choice for boolean variables. Just compare these codes:

```
if(boolVariable)
{
  //...
}
else
{
  //...
}
```

and it's equivalent

```
switch(boolVariable)
{
  case true:
    //...
    break;
  case false: // or default:
    //...
    break;
}
```

IMO `if` statement is more cleaner and readable and maintainnable :)

Answer (score 1):

On my opinion, the first code was more readable than that monster. If you're using C# 7 or higher, you can write the code like this:

```
switch (result)
{
    case true when isTrue:
        //Here is the code when both result and isTrue are true
    break;
    case true when actionType == 6:
        //Here is the code when both result and actionType is 6
    break;
    default:
        //Here defaultaction
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its not really wrong, but I wouldn't consider the last code block to be more readable.
 Personally, I would stick with `if ... else`, like this:

```
if (result) {
  if (isTrue) {
    // perform action
    return;
  } else if (actionType == 6) {
    isTrue = false;
    // perform action
    return;
  }
  // perform default action
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would not use switch clause for bool values. A more readable form of your code would be:

```
        if (!result)
            return;

        if (isTrue)
        {
            // do action
        }
        else if (actionType == 6)
        {
            // do something
        }
        else
        {
            // do the default action
        }
```

But this is not a good example of OOP code, I would suggest you to read about SOLID principles.

Comment: I know SOLID.. but a code written long time ago binds me to this approach unfortunately.

Comment: @BarrJ I still think the approach I answered your question is more readable than this (and it uses switch)

Comment: Yes it did. I will update an answer of mine to show my conclusion :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help! What I ended up doing, for number of reasons was:

```
 if (result)
 {
    if (isTrue)
    {
      //Perform action
    } 
    else 
    {
       switch (actionType)
       {
          case 6:
              //Perform action on 6
                break;
                   default:
                      //no condition mathed - write to log     
                break;
       }
    }
 }
```

I did prefer this approach and the reasons are:

**First** - If the type of the `actionType` variable changes, all I need to do is a small change in the case, instead of dealing with it inside `else-if` clause.

**Second**, if another condition is added I just need to add another case, instead of building a big nested `else-if` clause over the years.

**Third** - It is easier to maintain log record if no case is matched, inside the default case.

I considered all of the answers during the weekend and accepted @Sergey Berezovskiy answer, as the answer and link he posted helped me come to my final conclusion.